# Override the setter of a protocol-defined variable and use the getter from the protocol's default implementation

Tags: swift, overriding, protocols, extension-methods, default-implementation

I have a protocol with a single variable

```
protocol Localizable {
    var localizationKey: String { get set }
}
```

for which I implement a **default getter**:

```
extension Localizable {
    var localizationKey: String {
        get {
            assert(true, "❌ Do not use this getter! 
                          The localizationKey is a convenience variable 
                          for setting a localized string.")
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Now I make several classes conform to this protocol. In these classes I want to override the `localizationKey`'s setter but use the default implementation for its getter, for example:

```
extension UILabel: Localizable {

    var localizationKey: String {
        get {
            // ❓ Use default implementation from protocol extension here
        }
        set {
            text = LocalizedString(forKey: newValue)
        }
    }

}
```

### (How) can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is implement the variable observer `didSet` or `willSet`

Here's a snippet based on your code

```
protocol Localizable {
    var localizationKey: String { get set }
}


extension Localizable {
    var localizationKey: String {
        get {
            return ""
        }
    }
}

class UILabel: Localizable {

    var localizationKey: String {
        willSet
        {
            text = LocalizedString(forKey: newValue)
        }
    }

}
```

PD: I forget it. Extension cannot override properties, you should use the *willSet* snippet on a class

Comment: You're using inheritance here when you define `class UILabel: Localizable`. However, I want to define an *extension* on UILabel (and other existing UI components) in order to _add_ behavior to existing classes.

Comment: In an extension, when you implement a property defined in a protocol you **need** to implement both, the getter and the setter. Simply using `willSet` will cause a compile error.